# crear una lista con datos de otras listas en java

Tags: java, array, lista, arraylist, array-bidimensional

Imaginen que tengo estas listas bidimensionales de tipo List<String[]>.

```
Lista1=[["ServiceA",0,24,100,20],["ServiceB",63,42,150,30],["ServiceC",0,25,45,37]]

Lista2=[["ServiceB",1,34,130,20],["ServiceC",34,22,10,60],["ServiceD",10,242,5,35],["ServiceH",1,22,5,35]]

Lista3=[["ServiceA",2,24,100,20],["ServiceB",23,2,150,230],["ServiceD",12,25,465,83]]

Lista4=[["ServiceA",3,34,10,20],["ServiceB",44,2,10,130],["ServiceC",16,262,5,375]]
```

No siempre traen la misma longitud.
Hay una manera de crear una nueva lista a partir de los valores de las listas anteriores. manteniendo las diferencias.??

digamos que cada posición del arreglo es una columna: por ejemplo ["ServiceA",2,24,100,20]
[0]=Nombre del servicio

[1]=Success

[2]=Fail

[3]= Time

[4]= total
El nombre del servicio sería como su key/id

el resultado sería algo así:

Lista de Success---------

```
[nombre del servicio ,Success de lista 1,Success de lista 2,Success de lista 3,Success de lista 4]
```

Lista de Success---------

```
[["ServiceA",0,-,2,3],["ServiceB",63,34,23,44],["ServiceC",0,34,-,16],["ServiceD",-,10,465,-],["ServiceH",-,1,-,-]].
```

Intenté hacerlo como muchos for pero me salió el error de la memoria heap...
estoy utilizando java 8

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema que tienes lo resuelve la API de [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html), Concretamente el método `flatMap`. Un método tal que así puede ser la solución a tu pregunta:

```
static List<String[]> aplanarLista(List<List<String[]>> listas) {
    return listas.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

El main con el que lo he probado:

```
public class Main {
     static List<String[]> aplanarLista(List<List<String[]>> listas) {
         return listas.stream()
           .flatMap(List::stream)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<String[]> lista1= Arrays.asList(new String[] {"ServiceA","0","24","100","20"},new String[] {"ServiceB","0","24","100","20"});

        List<String[]> lista2= Arrays.asList(new String[] {"ServiceG","0","24","83","20"},new String[] {"ServiceE","38","24","100","20"});

        List<List<String[]>> listas = Arrays.asList(lista1, lista2);
        
        System.out.println(aplanarLista(listas)
                           .stream()
                           .map(Arrays::toString)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Saca lo siguiente:

```
[[ServiceA, 0, 24, 100, 20], [ServiceB, 0, 24, 100, 20], [ServiceG, 83, 20], [ServiceE, 38, 24, 100, 20]]
```